# Redirecting stdout via system(...,'-echo')

Tags: matlab, octave

I often call computationally intensive command-line programs from within `MATLAB` using the `system` command:

```
[status, result] = system(cmd_line_for_my_low_level_exe, '-echo');
```

where the `-echo` option (supposedly) echoes console output (stdout) generated by `low_level_exe` in the `MATLAB` command window.

On Linux machines this works great, with `MATLAB` echoing the console output in (seemingly) real-time. Users get a nice continuous update on `low_level_exe`'s progress.

On Windows machines this is not the case. It can often be many minutes in-between echoes, and users sometimes get impatient and assume the code has crashed...

Is there a way to increase/control the frequency of `MATLAB`'s `-echo`, or possibly another, better option entirely? (I'd prefer to stay away from `mex` files to maintain compatibility with `Octave`).

Is this actually a `MATLAB` issue, or just a Linux/Windows incompatibility?